# mysql, суммирование значений связанных таблиц

Tags: mysql

есть 3 связанные таблицы, главная таблица - категория, вторая таблица- оборудования, 3-пользователи. суммирую оборудования по категориям- проходит, суммирую пользователей по категориям - проходит, пытаюсь суммировать одновременно оборудования и пользователей - не проходит. возможно не правильно суммирую. ниже выложил запрос. помогите пожалуйста разобраться.

```
SELECT sum.name AS 'категория'
     , SUM(dslam.dslam) AS 'сумма' 
FROM dslam 
JOIN sum ON dslam.sats_id = sum.id 
GROUP BY sum.id;  

SELECT sum.name AS 'Категория'
     , COUNT(sats.sats_id) AS 'пользователи' 
FROM sats 
JOIN sum ON sats.sats_id = sum.id 
GROUP BY sum.id;
```

как-то так пытаюсь объединить запрос

```
SELECT sum.name AS 'категория', SUM(dslam.dslam) AS 'сумма', COUNT(sats.sats_id) AS'пользователи' FROM dslam JOIN sum ON dslam.sats_id = sum.id JOIN sats ON sats.sats_id = sum.id GROUP BY sum.id;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 1. Прикрепите к вопросу какие-нибудь тестовые данные. 2. Опишите результат, который вы хотите получить.

Comment: пытаюсь обобщить два запроса, щас выложу данные и результат

Comment: выложил, надеюсь что-то видно

Comment: *возможно не правильно суммирую.* Угу. Надо сначала суммировать в подзапросах, а потом только привязывать посчитанные суммы к категориям.

Comment: count distinct бы еще прокатило, но вот с суммой не получится

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT sum.name AS 'Категория',
     , dslam_agg.sum_dslam AS 'сумма' 
     , sats_agg.count_sats AS 'пользователи' 
FROM sum 
[LEFT] JOIN (SELECT dslam.sats_id AS id
                  , SUM(dslam.dslam) AS sum_dslam
             FROM dslam 
             GROUP BY dslam.sats_id) dslam_agg USING (id)
[LEFT] JOIN (SELECT sats.sats_id AS id
                  , COUNT(sats.sats_id) AS count_sats
             FROM sats 
             GROUP BY sats.sats_id) sats_agg USING (id)
```

Comment: понял, очень круто ! спасибо большое !  а  возможно ли произвести арифметические операции полученными результатами  ? например вычитание от 'суммы' - 'пользователи' ?

Comment: @Misterjunior А что собственно мешает-то?

Comment: синтактикс вычитания  еще не знаком,  логика понятна

Comment: @Misterjunior Синтаксис абсолютно такой же, как на арифметике в первом классе. Уменьшаемое минус вычитаемое. Подробности вон там: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/expressions.html

Comment: понял , надеюсь разберусь,  очень помогли , спасибо!